# How can I use LINQ and lambdas to perform a bitwise OR on a bit flag enumeration property of objects in a list?

Tags: c#, lambda, enums, bit-fields, aggregate

I have a collection of objects, and each object has a bit field enumeration property. What I am trying to get is the logical OR of the bit field property across the entire collection. How can I do this with out looping over the collection (hopefully using LINQ and a lambda instead)?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
[Flags]
enum Attributes{ empty = 0, attrA = 1, attrB = 2, attrC = 4, attrD = 8}

class Foo {
    Attributes MyAttributes { get; set; }
}

class Baz {
    List<Foo> MyFoos { get; set; }

    Attributes getAttributesOfMyFoos() {
        return // What goes here? 
    }
}
```

I've tried to use `.Aggregate` like this:

```
return MyFoos.Aggregate<Foo>((runningAttributes, nextAttributes) => 
    runningAttributes | nextAttribute);
```

but this doesn't work and I can't figure out how to use it to get what I want. Is there a way to use LINQ and a simple lambda expression to calculate this, or am I stuck with just using a loop over the collection?

Note: Yes, this example case is simple enough that a basic `foreach` would be the route to go since it's simple and uncomplicated, but this is only a boiled down version of what I am actually working with.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your query doesn't work, because you're trying to apply `|` on `Foo`s, not on `Attributes`. What you need to do is to get `MyAttributes` for each `Foo` in the collection, which is exaclty what `Select()` does:

```
MyFoos.Select(f => f.MyAttributes).Aggregate((x, y) => x | y)
```

Comment: While this requires 2 queries, it is still a nice, simple solution, and I believe is the most useful to me (even though not the best answer) because it helped me remember what it was that I am actually after.

Answer (score 2):

First, you’ll need to make `MyAttributes` public, otherwise you can’t access it from `Baz`.

Then, I think the code you’re looking for is:

```
return MyFoos.Aggregate((Attributes)0, (runningAttributes, nextFoo) => 
    runningAttributes | nextFoo.MyAttributes);
```

Comment: +1 for having the parameters in the wrong order, but 11 for using a magic number for the initial value. (just because it's 0 now doesn't mean it will stay that way).

Comment: @cdeszaq: The question clearly stated that the goal is to get the bitwise OR of all the values. For that, you *always* want to start with `0`. If I had used one of the enum values (`empty` in his case), *that* might change and then the code would be wrong. Using the constant `0` is the correct way.

Comment: Or alternatively, `default(Attributes)`.